# What would be the alternate command for mate gemfile for some other editor in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started with rails tutorial but there was the use of mate editor in that which is for apple OS but i m using windows and have installed a recommended editor komodo edit.

What can be the alternative to this for **komodo edit**?
**$ mate Gemfile**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I follow but `mate Gemfile` is no different to just opening any editor and doing File -> Open and selecting the file Gemfile. It's just an alias for opening the application TextMate and opening the file Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Mate command on Windows, you must first add Notepad (or any other editor you'd like) as the main program

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\ProgramData\...notepad location' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

And then you will be able to create the file by writting

```
start notepad README.md
```